# Lua table access efficiency

Tags: performance, lua, lua-table

I have a question about accessing data in a Lua table.
Say, there is a large Lua table like following:

```
 tbl = {
         {
           blockIdx = 5,
           key1 = "val1",
           key2 = "val2",
           ...
         },
         {
           blockIdx = 30,
           key1 = "val11",
           key2 = "val12",
           ...
         },
         {
           blockIdx = 83,
           key1 = "val21",
           key2 = "val22",
           ...
         },
         ...
       }
```

And now I want to find one of the block that `blockIdx` is , for example, `38`.
So normally, I would like to use `for` to find the block:

```
for k,v in pairs(tbl) do
     if v.blockIdx == 38 then
        blahFunction(v)
     end
end
```

But I don't think it is a good idea especially for large table.
So I modify the table a bit:

```
 tbl = {
         [5] = { 
           key1 = "val1",
           key2 = "val2",
           ...
         },
         [30] = {
           key1 = "val11",
           key2 = "val12",
           ...
         },
         [83] = {
           key1 = "val21",
           key2 = "val22",
           ...
         },
         ...
       }
```

Then I can easily access my block with one line:

```
blahFunction(tbl[38])
```

So my question is, is there any performance different between two method?
Maybe doing `tbl[38]` actually did a `for` loop inside Lua?
Or just like an array in C/C++ we can direct access memory using `[ ]` without `for` loop,
witch obviously has much better performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The performance is different, the second method is more efficient.

Internally, a Lua table contains an array part and a hash part, if the table is a sequence, then the sequence part is implemented by the array part. But the table in your second example is not a sequence, it's probably implemented by the hash part. The performance in this case is not like accessing arrays in C/C++, but like accessing a hash, which is still pretty fast.

So in conclusion, the second piece of code is faster, because it doesn't iterate through the elements like in your first example.

Comment: @Schollii I'm not following you on this. To access an element in a hash, all is needed is to calculate the hash code of the key and find the element using that hash code. It's not as fast as array access, but assuming the hash function is good enough, it's still rather fast (O(1) in average case, O(lgN) in worst case).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo ah yes yes yes the hash function makes it an O(1) operation, sorry for the noise, I was thinking of a different structure. my comments are misleading so I will remove.

Comment: @YuHao: Worst case for a `find` operation in a hash table... O(lgN)? I thought it was linear in the number of elements.